# Cocos2D port for XNA (windows phone)

Tags: c#, cocos2d-iphone, xna, wrapper

Do you know any working port of Cocos2D which could be used by windows phone game (XNA) ?

to be clear, i've searching for it and found port which use Mono, but it isn't the best choice for me, at least not before spend few hours to use XNA instead of Mono(GL).

Comment: FYI, if you can't find it for XNA you're out of luck. Mono/GL can't run on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2D for XNA Blog Announcement

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1801

Still in Beta at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

[CocosNet](https://github.com/city41/CocosNet)

Answer (score 0):

try this port also for windows phone also compatible for windows phone 8
http://wpcoco.codeplex.com
writen from scratch

Answer (score 0):

The cocos2d-xna project is released now. You can get the source at https://github.com/Cocos2DXNA/cocos2d-xna or via nuget package at nuget.cocos2dxna.com/nuget